What are the Basics for printing labels with a Godex thermal transfer printer (G530) on linux ubuntu?(lp / lpr)
I'm using libreOffice Draw to create a basic hello world label pdf file to use with lp / lpr and the main Issue I'm facing is that when printing the label is off to the right side by 10mm when printing from the "print gui" in the libreoffice draw or the lp new.pdf command and I'd like to offset the print ~10mm to the left. I've tryed this but the parameter -o page-left=100 doesn't seem to have an effect.
Now through ubuntu's(24.04) gui in "printer settings" for the Godex G530 particular settings I am able affect the offsets in the "Media size" tab but not x y specifically which is prolemattic when using custom labels etc... and when choosing "custome for the media" instead of just printing the label with the offset(when it was set to 50x25mm which I'm also using such stickers as the labels) it just creates a more offsetted black rect filled blob at the right buttom corner.
So the basic question is how to print thermal transfer labels with set offset (from pdf as fit the page) on linux?
Info:
OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Printer: Godex G530
Printer Driver: as manufacturer suggested in youtube video installation from website
Stickers: 50*25mm PP 71mm Wide with 4mm gap between labels)
Ribbon: Resin (Doesn't matter)

try installing gLabels from the software centre. You might have more siuccess there

I did and unless you make the "label width" longer than in actually is and then comhensate it with the margin it still won't let you do the offset.
also i suspect that I have quality issues regarding thin small lines and it smirs a little across ONLY the vertical sweep for some reason...

I seem to recall that smearing is a "feature" of thermal printers. I've never had an issue with gLabels on non standard label sizes. Did you research the database to find labels that match the size of the ones your are using?

I was actually expecting there to be a comphensation for label media size calibration on thta software by defualt here are my sticker actual measurements:

Sticker area: 50*25mm

Pitch: 28.8mm
Offset from left to sticker endge: ~10.4mm
Offset from right to sticker endge: ~10.4mm
Roll width: 71.2mm



The standard sizes seem retarded for that kind of printer so I think I have no choise but to to create a "custome label" using this software...
